# Why is cadence only doing task deletion queries on my DB

Tags: cadence-workflow, uber-cadence

For the past 30 minutes, this is the only db query being done by my cadence server

```
delete from
  tasks
where
  domain_id = ?
  and task_list_name = ?
  and task_type = ?
  and task_id <= ?
order by
  domain_id,
  task_list_name,
  task_type,
  task_id
limit
  ?
```

Any idea why this might be happening ? None of my workflows are getting picked and are getting timed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s for cleaning up the unused tasks entries.

This is also due to the fact that SQL databases like MySQL doesn’t have TTL features. If a task doesn’t get pulled within its timeout , it will stay there forever until it's scanned and removed.

See the code here: https://github.com/uber/cadence/blob/c5863ebf7c646ff6e60205ef3f0895199e823749/service/worker/scanner/tasklist/scavenger.go#L116